Azure Policy to prevent overly permissive NSG rules being created?
I want to be able to create a policy within Azure that prevents users from creating inbound NSG allow rules for ports 3389/22 from any/ internet source, either manually or via the options within the JIT-access menu.
I've tried creating a policy definition for this as per the below, but when testing it doesn't apply to the resources within its scope, it still lets me create any rule I like.
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Prevent creating RDP/SSH rule that allows any/ internet-based connections inbound to a VM",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "metadata": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "category": "Virtual Machine NSG Restriction",
      "createdBy": "a8321135-8365-4f57-863c-4ab27962ff0c",
      "createdOn": "2024-08-08T07:58:37.3955217Z",
      "updatedBy": "a8321135-8365-4f57-863c-4ab27962ff0c",
      "updatedOn": "2024-08-08T09:26:10.0736027Z"
    },
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules"
          },
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/direction",
            "equals": "Inbound"
          },
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/access",
            "equals": "Allow"
          },
          {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix",
                "equals": "*"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix",
                "equals": "0.0.0.0/0"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange",
                "equals": "3389"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange",
                "equals": "22"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange",
                "equals": "*"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
      }
    },
    "versions": [
      "1.0.0"
    ]
  },
  "id": "/subscriptions/[mysubscriptionID]/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/ab8771fb-c58c-42f3-b935-d8492919d5f7",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "ab8771fb-c58c-42f3-b935-d8492919d5f7",
  "systemData": {
    "createdBy": "[myusername]",
    "createdByType": "User",
    "createdAt": "2024-08-08T07:58:37.3659311Z",
    "lastModifiedBy": "[myusername]",
    "lastModifiedByType": "User",
    "lastModifiedAt": "2024-08-08T09:26:10.0603055Z"
  }
}

Can anyone advise how to set this up properly? Or if there is an easier way of achieving the same result?


Azure Policy to prevent overly permissive NSG rules being created?

Here is the updated policy to prevent the creation of inbound NSG allow rules for ports 3389 and 22 from any internet source.

Note: If the policy is not working, make sure to check the policy compliance state and the scope of the policy.

{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/access",
          "equals": "Allow"
        },
                {
          "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/direction",
          "equals": "Inbound"
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix",
              "equals": "*"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix",
              "equals": "0.0.0.0/0"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange",
              "equals": "3389"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange",
              "equals": "22"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange",
              "equals": "*"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}

JIT blocking policy
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Security/locations/jitNetworkAccessPolicies"
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Security/locations/jitNetworkAccessPolicies/virtualMachines[*].ports[*].number",
              "equals": "3389"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Security/locations/jitNetworkAccessPolicies/virtualMachines[*].ports[*].number",
              "equals": "22"
            },
                 {
              "field": "Microsoft.Security/locations/jitNetworkAccessPolicies/requests[*].virtualMachines[*].ports[*].number",
              "equals": "22"
            },
                 {
              "field": "Microsoft.Security/locations/jitNetworkAccessPolicies/requests[*].virtualMachines[*].ports[*].number",
              "equals": "3389"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}

After applying the azure policy at the subscription scope, the policy is blocking the NSG rule.

Compliance Result


Thanks for this, this works perfectly when adding rules manually, but doesn't seem to when selecting "All Associated IP's" when adding a JIT-access rule to a VM (which adds a rule to allow 3389 from any source). Is it possible to restrict this as well?

Hi @Elliot, You need to create an additional policy to block NSG rules for ports 3389 and 22 that are created via JIT.

Updated answer for blocking NSG rules for ports 3389 and 22 that are created via JIT

Hi @Venkat V the JIT policy doesn't work unfortunately, it still allows the creation of NSG rules for 3389/22 from any source when done via JIT. Any ideas?

Hi @Elliot, Refer this link for JIT : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/846584/azure-vm-jit-do-not-allow-any-as-source, Meanwhile I will check the policy on my environment.

You can also prevent the user from configuring or editing the JIT policy for a VM using RBAC custom role: create a custom role without this action: Microsoft.Security/locations/jitNetworkAccessPolicies/write, Refer the MS Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/just-in-time-access-usage#prerequisites for more details.
